# Search algorithm required

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I need a c# program ( search algorithm ), ie, When user types a character, the display should update to show all valid choices for the next character and a list of possible matching stations.

Ex: User Input: D A R T, it should display

DARTFORD and DARTMOUTH

Suggested outline is below:

```
public class Suggestions
{
     HashSet<Character> nextLetters { get; set; }
     HashSet<String> stations { get; set; }
}

public class StationFinder
{
     private static String[] stations = new String[] {"LIVERPOOL LIME STREET", "BIRMINGHAM 
                                       NEW STREET", "KINGSTON", " DARTFORD", "DARTMOUTH" };

    public Suggestions GetSuggestions( String userInput )
    {
          // TODO Compute result
          Suggestions result = new Suggestions();
          return result;
    }
}
```

This is just a suggestion it can be modified as well.

Regards,
Vishnu

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Dude you did not even tag it for .net and this smells like homework

Answer (score 1):

I do not know C# personally so I can't help you with the code but what you want to use is called a [TRIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This is a specific type of tree structure for strings.  The nice property is you can very see all legal endings given the starting of a string.  This is perfect for things like auto suggest etc. and I think is what you want for you thing.  just google around for TRIE implementations in C#

Comment: Tries are good if you have huge word lists like dictionaries; if you have a couple of thousand items, just iterating through a list/array and picking the ones with the right `.StartsWith()` is both easier and sufficiently performant.

Comment: I gave a +1 but I do this with several thousand and LINQ in 0.1 seconds.  But I am going to look at TRIE.  Based on the sample I doubt this is a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I can try the TRIE implementation.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Ternary search tree look [here wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree) and [here c# example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84860/Ternary-Search-Tree-Algorithm-for-word-list-storag)

Comment: This is a decent answer, the Wiki link also states that Hash tables can be used, which is what I was going to say LOL. +1